# Are smart contract data outputs hashed?

Tags: contract-development, transactions, contract-deployment

Last year a colleague and I ran a physics simulation in block #9360178, and published it here: Chem. Sci. 2020, 11, 4644.

The transaction ID is: 0x36b510f3bdb2fa67a0d4f749899ab8630b54000ee5a211172d699d750f94f94f. The block hash is: 0x6cb36c1011265387c7933e199c1de8a9f3a5ca59fa45ec9e5dd6f388884f958a.

I would like to know if the output of this transaction, ie. the result of the simulation, was actually hashed, and if so, is it included in the block hash shown?

Comment: use tenderly https://dashboard.tenderly.co/tx/mainnet/0x36b510f3bdb2fa67a0d4f749899ab8630b54000ee5a211172d699d750f94f94f/debugger?trace=0

Comment: Can you show the contract code? When you say output what do you mean? returned value, emitted event, stored data.. What's the output supposed to be? Returned values by functions are [ABI encoded](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.4/abi-spec.html), similarly with events. I think the only case where an event parameter is hashed is for indexed strings.

Comment: The contract code is on pages 14-16 here: https://www.rsc.org/suppdata/d0/sc/d0sc01523g/d0sc01523g1.pdf

It's the line "return res;". Does that mean that the block hash shown doesn't include any direct or provably related hash of that returned value?

Comment: @MagnusHanson-Heine The returned value by a function is not part of the block. You have to use a tool like the one MadeInDreams indicates.

Comment: The "OUTPUT" hex string shown on that site or a site like etherscan.io does correspond to the simulation output values that were returned. Where are these sites getting that output data from if the output isn't stored in a block?